# how to serialUser work local and google

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

```
//**In LocalStrategy**
passport.serializeUser(
    function(user, done){
        done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(
    function(id, done){
        User.findById(id, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                done(err);
            }
            done(null, user);
        });
});

//**google stratergy**
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, obj);
});
```

**I wanted to use both auth method in one application but if i'm using google stratergy serializeUser it take user but in local it takes user.id and while deserializeUser one take id and another obj how can i make both work together**